# Oauth identity toolkit

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am at last step to configure the identity tool kit login authentication , so they talk about configure server side " There are two code snippets at the bottom of the page. The first snippet helps make the JavaScript configuration easy for your website. The second snippet should be saved in your server side code directory as gitkit-server-config.json.
The server side configuration file needs to be further configured before use. Open the file for editing and change serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile setting to be equal to the path of the *.p12 or *.json file you downloaded earlier. You should use the full path, beginning with / and ending with the full name of the *.p12 or *.json file"  can any one help me

Comment: I found documentations but every one was different , also I ask what s the server side file ???

Comment: you should at least show the link to the procedure you are following,  don't assume everyone is familiar with it.

Comment: Can I move to use 0auth 2.0 if is not so complicated  to configure ??

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/configure-service  : this is the link and am blocked at H and I at the bottom